# Custom label class do not show the text PqQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have some problem with custom label class in PyQt5. Code below does not show label text, just empty window. I've searched the internet, but have not found the answer.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel


class Label(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        QLabel.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(40, 400, 100, 100)
        self.setText("This text does not appear")


class MyWin(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 500, 500)
        self.ABC = Label()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MyWin()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i ve tried `self.ABC = Label(self)` instead of `self.ABC = Label()`, but it come up with error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set a parent for a widget, it will become a top level widget (a standalone "window").

You can add a widget to a parent by adding that parent to the constructor (`SomeWidgetClass(parent)`) or by calling [`setParent(parent)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) after it's created.

Your subclass doesn't accept any argument in its `__init__` (that's why you get an error if you do `Label(self)`), so it's considered a top level window; it is also not shown as such because top level windows require to manually call `show()` in order to display them.

The solution is simple:

```
class Label(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(40, 400, 100, 100)
        self.setText("This text does not appear")

class MyWin(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 500, 500)
        self.ABC = Label(self)
```

Consider that using fixed geometries for child widgets is highly discouraged, and [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should be used instead.

When you set a layout for a parent widget and add a child widget to that layout, the widget will be automatically displayed as soon as the parent becomes visible. In this case, you don't really need to add the parent to the constructor, as the widget that uses that layout takes "the ownership" of the child automatically (it is "reparented").

Also, you should always set a [`central widget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) on QMainWindows (even if it's just a placeholder); that central widget will act as a "container" for the actual contents of the main window.

```
class MyWin(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 500, 500)

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central.setLayout(layout)

        self.ABC = Label()
        layout.addWidget(self.ABC)
```

<sub>A suggestion: avoid using capitalized names for variables and attributes; prefer `self.abc` instead of `self.ABC`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Widget without parent `self.abc = Label()` is a window,
which can be shown by `self.abc.show()`.

You need to pass the parent `self.abc = Label(self)` when instantiating the object and add it to the calass

```
class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                # parent
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)         # parent
        ...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel


class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                  # parent
        super(Label, self).__init__(parent)           # parent
        
        self.setGeometry(40, 400, 100, 100)
        self.setText("This text does not appear")


class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(1000, 500, 500, 500)
        self.abc = Label(self)                        # self
        self.abc.adjustSize() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWin()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]